# Password writing system: standard output no longer works

Tags: python, python-3.x, system

I'm currently working on a personnal project and I try to create a password function. So I wrote this script :

```py
import getch
import sys

print("votre mot de passe : ", end="")
passwor = ''
while True:
    x = getch.getch()
    if x == '\n':
        break
    sys.stdout.write("*")
    passwor += x

print('\n'+passwor)
```

But I'm stucking on a problem : nothing appear on my output console
It apear the problem come from end="" argument from print and sys.stdout.write("*"). I try to remove both and it working proprely (I change sys.stdout.write("*") by print("*")). 
I made some research and I found a solution : if I run my script like : `python3 -u <my_script>` it works
But I want to call this function on an another file... so it should be great if I can run my scipt without -u argument...
Does it exist a solution ?
Just for information : [os:debian(wsl),version:python3.7.3]

Comment: Instead of creating your own password input, you could just use [getpass](http://docs.python.org/library/getpass.html#getpass.getpass). Generally, it is better to use existing solutions for security-relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Python 3.3 or later, you can write `print("votre mot de passe : ", end="", flush=True)` and it will automatically force Python to write everything in the output buffer to the terminal. You can also flush the output buffer manually by writing `sys.stdout.flush()` after printing.

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It will not replace password characters with * but it does the job of not printing anything to the stdout while you are typing.

```
from getpass import getpass

password = getpass(prompt="votre mot de passe: ")
print(password)
```

Comment: I already see this option but I realy want  "*" in place of my input ^^"